# Rails - Change html element based on time elspased from a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, datepicker

Okay my title might not be the best way to describe what I'm trying to do, but how, in general, could I accomplish changing the color of a div (by applying different css classes) based on the amount of time away from a date?

I'm using this:

```
<%= todo.due ? todo.due.strftime("%b %d") : nil %>
```

to display a due date.

It's wrapped in a div and I'd like to change the class of that div if the due date is more than a week away, 3 days away, today or past due.

Should this be handled with some controller logic, or would if else statements in the view work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this in your helper

```
def css_select(due) 
  css_class = "passed" #=> deadline already passed
  days_due = (due - Date.today).to_i
  if days_due > 0
     css_class = case  days_due
                   when (0..3) then "threedays" #=> between 3 days
                   when (3..7) then "within7days" #=> between 7 days
                   else
                   "morethanweek" #=> more than a week
                end 
  end
  css_class
end
```

Please note that, `threedays, passed, within7days and morethanweek` are css classes that you might want to change the name of.

these are the test I did

```
p css_select(Date.parse("2012-12-01")) #=> passed
p css_select(Date.parse("2012-12-25")) #=> with in 3 days
p css_select(Date.parse("2012-12-31")) #=> with in 7 days
p css_select(Date.parse("2013-01-10")) #=> more then 7 days
```

so in your view

```
<div class=<%= css_select(Date.parse(todo.due)) %>
  #your code goes here
</div>
```

so when you are in the view, and this answer was inspired by the answer givne by @Valery Kvon

HTH

Comment: Thanks! I get this error though: ```can't convert ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String```

Comment: I think its something with the date parsing, try to parse your date as shown in my example Date.parse("2012-12-01")

Comment: Sorry for my late reply here (gotta spend time w/ the family for the holiday...), but it works! ```<div class="timelabel <%= css_select(Date.parse(todo.due.to_s)) %>">``` is what I ended up doing to get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is too easy...

Helper:

1) By daytime:

```
def style_by_daytime
  case Time.now.hour
  when (6..14) then "morning"
  when (14..20) then "daytime"
  when (20..23) then "evening"
  when (0..6) then "night"
  end
end
```

2) By time ago

```
def style_by_days_gone(by_date)
  ago = (Date.today - by_date).round
  case ago
  when (1..7) then "week"
  when (8..14) then "two_weeks"
  when (15..30) then "month"
  when (31..180) then "several_months"
  else
    if ago > 180
      "many_time_ago"
    end  
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% if todo.due %>
 <div class="<%= style_by_days_gone(todo.due) %>">
   <%= todo.due.strftime("%b %d") %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Using ```style_by_days_gone``` though, you're defining that the date to go by is December 1, 2012 right? That should be determined dynamically by whatever the ```todo.due``` value is. Am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: You seeing this right. Date.today - whatever_date returns the age. Updated with todo.due...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [content_tag helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) and provide a custom class value. The class value can be placed in a helper.

View:

```
<%= content_tag :div, :class => todo_class(todo) do -%>
  <%= todo.title %>
<% end -%>
```

Helper:

```
def todo_class(todo)
  if todo.due
    'due'
  ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. But I'm still not sure how to set up the options for displaying the different css classes. Like in the helper would I need to do a little arithmetic to calculate the number of days until a todo reaches the value of its due date? I suppose Rails doesn't have anything built in (or any gems that you know of) that handle this type of thing huh?

Comment: Yes, the it would be in the helper. To better understand your problem it would be helpful if you would add more details to the question. What exactly do you want to change and under which circumstances?